# SAS: validating SASApp - Stored Process Server

Tags: sas

I try to validate the SASApp - Stored Process Server through SAS Management console. But the error is occured here:

[20.01.14 16:49] INFO: Starting extended validation for Stored Process server (level 1) - Making a connection
[20.01.14 16:49] SEVERE: Connection refused: connect
[20.01.14 16:49] SEVERE: The application could not log on to the server "*server*:8601". No server is available at that port on that machine.

I've checked in the properties the port for this server is 8601. 
The official SAS Institute patch from http://support.sas.com/kb/46/844.html didn't solve the problem.

Has anybody had the same problem?

Answer (score 3):

Four years late, but I ran into the same issue during a deployment workshop twice this week- both times it was because of a password mismatch with the service account responsible for accessing the servers.  I re-updated the password in SAS Management Console and updated the password using deployment manager and then reattempted the validation and was successful.  Hope this helps anyone else having the same issue!

More on updating passwords through Deployment Manager can be found here: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/Updating-Managed-Passwords/ta-p/361613